# How to direct multiple routes to the same method in Backbone JS?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, routes, dry

This is my routes object in a BackboneJS app:

```
       routes: {
            ""               : "_navigate",
            "home"           : "_navigate",
            "blog"           : "_navigate",
            "photos"         : "_navigate",
            "notes"          : "_navigate",
            "about"          : "_navigate",
            "singlepost_:id" : "_navigate"
        },
```

it redirects routes to the `_navigate` method, which looks like this:

```
        _navigate: function(postId) {
            if (postId) {
               // show single entry
               return;
            }

            // show regular entry
        },
```

It works perfectly fine. However, I find the repetitive routes object to be annoying.

My question is: Is there a better way to direct all these routes to the same method without repeating yourself so much?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-router/ Check out the section on splats

> Any "*splats" or ":params" in route definitions are passed as
>   arguments (in respective order) to the associated function. A route
>   defined as "/:route/:action" will pass 2 variables (“route” and
>   “action”) to the callback function. (If this is confusing please post
>   a comment and I will try articulate it better) Here are some examples
>   of using ":params" and "*splats"

```
routes: {

        "/posts/:id": "getPost",
        // <a href="http://example.com/#/posts/121">Example</a>

        "/download/*path": "downloadFile",
        // <a href="http://example.com/#/download/user/images/hey.gif">Download</a>

        "/:route/:action": "loadView",
        // <a href="http://example.com/#/dashboard/graph">Load Route/Action View</a>

    },

    getPost: function( id ){ 
        alert(id); // 121 
    },
    downloadFile: function( path ){ 
        alert(path); // user/images/hey.gif 
    },
    loadView: function( route, action ){ 
        alert(route + "_" + action); // dashboard_graph 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite simple, really.

```
        routes: {
            "*actions:_id": "_navigate"
        }
```

---

Thanks to Jason Strimpel from the BackboneJS Google Group.